# how to sleep in c

Tags: c, sleep

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does printf not flush after the call unless a newline is in the format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin)

When I run something like

```
for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    sleep(1);
    printf(".");
}
```

then what I would expect is one dot per second ten times. What I get is ten dots once after ten seconds. Why is that so, and how do I get the program to actually print one point (or do other things) each second (or different time interval)?

Comment: _how to sleep in c_ ? Try `for (int i = 0; i < big_number; i++) ;` and disable optimization. I have production code here (not mine) that actually does that ^_^

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `printf()` is buffering the data, you can force it to flush that data with `fflush(stdout)`:

```
for (i = 1; i<=10; i++) 
{  
    sleep(1); 
    printf("."); 
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

Comment: thats what i thought... just didnt know about fflush() thanks :)